# AWS cognito does not generate tokens when run from a serverlet

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get amazon cognito to work. If I run the code to generate a login token from a standalone java program it works.

```
public class cognito extends HttpServlet
{


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("*******", "********");

AmazonCognitoIdentityClient client =
new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(credentials);
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)); 
GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest tokenRequest =
new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest();
tokenRequest.setIdentityPoolId("*************");
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

//Key -> Developer Provider Name used when creating the identity pool
//Value -> Unique identifier of the user in your <u>backend</u>
map.put("test", "AmazonCognitoIdentity");

//Duration of the generated OpenID Connect Token
tokenRequest.setLogins(map);
tokenRequest.setTokenDuration(1000l);

GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult result = client
.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(tokenRequest);
String identityId = result.getIdentityId();
String token = result.getToken();

System.out.println("id = " + identityId + "  token = " + token);


} 

}
```

However when I run this code from a servlet on a redhat linux server, it always times out.
Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: can you paste the real error messages?

Answer (score 0):

map.put("test", "AmazonCognitoIdentity");

are you sure your developer provider name is "test"?

you can see it in your cognito identity pool edit page.
And "AmazonCognitoIdentity" should be your own unique user-id.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual exception, it is hard to tell what is the exact issue.  It could be that something else running in your servlet engine is setting a much more aggressive socket timeout than the default when it runs from the command line.  You might want to explicitly set the connection and socket timeouts using methods using this class http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html and pass it in to the identity client constructor.